# Can my friend send money (from a different country) to my NRE account?

Tags: india, savings, saudi-arabia

I have an NRE account and I am saving completely through that account. Now one of my friends is working in Saudi Arabia and has to pay some money to my NRE account, which I opened from Dubai. Is it possible to make the transaction ?

Comment: Have you tried asking the bank where you hold the NRE account? Has your friend tried asking whatever service your friend will be using (e.g. Xoom) if this is possible? Your friend will need to specify a _reason_ for the money transfer to you, and the money might be taxable income to you in India.  It is not the different countries that is an issue but _who_ is making the deposit, and why.

Answer (score 1):

Yes anyone can credit an NRE account from outside. Most Banks in Dubai should be able to do this [The charges maybe higher], there are other remittance services offered from leading Indian banks like HDFC, ICICI, SBI, Axis etc.

A purpose of remittance needs to be provided, ask your Bank / Service Provider in Dubai and they should be able to tell your friend more details.